# Exclude hidden element from form submission in html

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to submit a form, however within this form there is a hidden element. This element is essential for the workings of this page and it was created to act as a template for the same element that will be cloned and appended to other parts of the script.

```
$("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
        var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
        element.removeClass("hidden").insertAfter(".samplesinfo:last");
```

The insert elements of the hidden template is set with the "disabled" attribute, and I am attempting to remove the disabled attr along with the copying of the clones, but not removing the disabled attr from the hidden element.

```
$("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
    var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
    element.removeClass("hidden").removeAttr("disabled").insertAfter(".samplesinfo:last");
```

I have tried variations of the above example, but no luck. Does anybody have any ideas or alternative solutions. I played around with the idea of placing the template outside the  and appending clones inside it without having to use the disabled option, but the clones never append within the form.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the form code.

Comment: On submit of the form `remove()` the hidden elements, or better yet, don't use hidden elements if they aren't meant to be included in the form submission. There's plenty of alternative ways to store information in the page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The template is necessary so that if the initial visible template is deleted, it can be re-added.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a reason you explicitly *need* to use hidden inputs, but I can't offer any workable alternatives without seeing a working example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would like to show you, but it is quite a large piece of code with jQuery integrated everywhere. I would have to publish my entire projext